# REACT : How to deal with disable onclick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While mapping array, i want to check other elements' classlist in the array. Want to stop manipulate classlist if any button clicked before. Here is the code and issue photo

```
const questionElements = questions.map((question) => {

    // ANSWERS ARRAY AND SHUFFLE
    let answers = [...question.incorrect_answers,question.correct_answer]
    shuffle(answers)

    // TOGGLE BUTTON BACKGROUND COLOR WHEN BTN CLICKED
    function toggleBtnBgColor(btn) {
        btn.target.classList.toggle("dark-bg-color")
    }

    return (
        <div key={nanoid()}>
            <div className="question" key={nanoid()}>{question.question}</div>
            {answers.map((answer)=> {
                return (
                    <button key={nanoid()} onClick={toggleBtnBgColor} className="answer-button">{answer}</button>
                )
            })}
            <hr></hr>
        </div>
    )
})

return (
    <div className="question-container">
        {questionElements}
    </div>
)
```

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nObos.png)

Comment: How about keeping a boolean value for each question and setting it to TRUE if a click is invoked on any answer?

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end of manipulation? Also I want to note that you are creating dynamic `key` for you elements that doesn't make sense. You should store keys in your array from the start (it can be id of your questions for instance)

Comment: @RustyNail i want to disable onclick event for all buttons in the same question if any button clicked before

Comment: @RustyNail how can i store keys in order while mapping array

Comment: I'll answer you with codesandbox example, if don't understand something i'll try to explain

Comment: Ok i did store keys, i add index parameter for each question element. I am trying to solve issue with unique keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check please [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-chaum-xy6dx9?file=/src/App.js). It can be a little complicated for you but feel free to ask questions

We use `useState` as a store for keys and answers flags. When we update our store via `setQuestions` with each update we calculate `answersDisabled` and pass it through props in answer component.

Example isn't perfect but I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I am still confused about some part of my react code. I decided to seperate the data from api instead store questions in state. Then i plan to build question object and set questions and boolean flag for answer buttons. Recent issue is that when i get data from api, repeats itself 4 times. Let me show you code and console. Many thanks for help.

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState()
// FETCH QUIZ DATA FROM API
const fetchData = () => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&type=multiple")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => setData(data.results))
}

console.log(data)

React.useEffect(()=> {
    fetchData()
},[])
```

Here is console [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNLtL.png) <----

Comment: I know not a big problem but worry about what is behind it

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED ! Seperated Question component from Quiz.js. Passed needed props to the components. Many thanks for all. Here is code

```js
import React from "react"
import { nanoid } from "nanoid"

export default function Question(props) {
    const [flag,setFlag] = React.useState(true)

    // TOGGLE BUTTON BACKGROUND COLOR WHEN BTN CLICKED
    function toggleBtnBgColor(btn) {
        if(flag) {
            btn.target.classList.toggle("dark-bg-color")
            setFlag(false)
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="question" key={props.index}>{props.question}</div>
                {props.answers.map((answer,index)=> {
                    return (
                        <button key={index} onClick={toggleBtnBgColor} className="answer-button">{answer}</button>
                    )
            })}
            <hr></hr>
        </>
    )
}
```

Here is Quiz.js

```js
import React from "react"
import Question from "./Question"

export default function Quiz() {

    const [data, setData] = React.useState([])

    // FETCH QUIZ DATA FROM API
    const fetchData = () => {
        fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&type=multiple")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => setData(data.results))
    }

    React.useEffect(()=> {
        fetchData()
    },[])

    // SHUFFLE ALGORITHM TO USE LATER
    function shuffle(array) {
        let currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;
      
        // While there remain elements to shuffle.
        while (currentIndex != 0) {
      
          // Pick a remaining element.
          randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
          currentIndex--;
      
          // And swap it with the current element.
          [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
            array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
        }
      
        return array;
    }

    const questionElements = data.map((question, index) => {
        // ANSWERS ARRAY AND SHUFFLE
        let answers = [...question.incorrect_answers,question.correct_answer]
        shuffle(answers)

        return (
            <Question key={index} index={index} question={question.question} answers={answers}/>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div className="question-container">
            {questionElements}
        </div>
    )

}
```